# PDF to LaTeX converter

Tags: gratis, pdf, document-converter, latex

I am searching for a free software that converts a PDF in a LaTeX file.

Actually I don't need it to convert the whole PDF, I just need to "extract" the formulas and use them to make my own LaTeX file.

Comment: See [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org/):

- free
- generate LaTeX from images of math formulas (source image files must be in TIF, PNG, or GIF formats)
- far from perfect in terms of accuracy, but I'm not aware of better.

[Other ideas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1443/11400).

Comment: I hoped there was something more complete. Fortunately 5 pages a day is still a good limit to me :-), thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [im2markup](https://github.com/harvardnlp/im2markup) to convert images of mathematical equations to LaTeX mathematical equations:

- Deng, Yuntian, Anssi Kanervisto, and Alexander M. Rush. "What You Get Is What You See: A Visual Markup Decompiler." arXiv preprint arXiv:1609.04938 (2016). https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04938
- open source: ANN-based, Torch7

> Building on recent advances in image caption generation and optical character recognition (OCR), we present a general-purpose, deep learning-based system to decompile an image into presentational markup. While this task is a well-studied problem in OCR, our method takes an inherently different, data-driven approach. Our model does not require any knowledge of the underlying markup language, and is simply trained end-to-end on real-world example data. The model employs a convolutional network for text and layout recognition in tandem with an attention-based neural machine translation system. To train and evaluate the model, we introduce a new dataset of real-world rendered mathematical expressions paired with LaTeX markup, as well as a synthetic dataset of web pages paired with HTML snippets. Experimental results show that the system is surprisingly effective at generating accurate markup for both datasets. While a standard domain-specific LaTeX OCR system achieves around 25% accuracy, our model reproduces the exact rendered image on 75% of examples.

[image]