# Converting a LaTeX-generated PDF into EPUB format, preserving formulas

Tags: pdf, document-converter, epub

Is there a software or a service out there that can take a technical article in PDF format (which typically contains LaTeX formulas) and convert it into an EPUB format? I wouldn’t have access to the original LaTeX files themselves, just the PDF.

I’d prefer Linux, but Windows would be ok, too.

The price is not important.

Comment: What operating system you need? Does the software need to be gratis or can it cost money? Is an online service okay?

Comment: Linux preferred, but windows would do.  If it costs money that's OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF to LaTeX converter](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/pdf-to-latex-converter)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Here it’s about PDF→EPUB, while the linked question is about PDF→LaTeX (and possibly formulas only).